# Interface Names for Connected Networks in MACOSX (Like ETHERNET , WIFI) Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to get the Names of the connected interfaces like ethernet with **IP addresses** , I am able to get the IP addresses for connected networks but unable to differentiate the IP addresses, Please help me with a solution

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can do that with `getifaddrs()`of `ifaddrs.h` and `SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()` of `SystemConfiguration.framework`

Comment: Can  u please provide me with sample code @vadian

Comment: Did you search SO? For example [iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically) and [how-to-find-the-hardware-type-of-an-interface-on-ios-and-mac-os-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705580/how-to-find-the-hardware-type-of-an-interface-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/35708797#35708797)

Comment: Thanks @vadian it actually helped me in acheiving my task , Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Network Interface Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727807/convert-network-interface-name)