# How to convert swift code to objective c code

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

for interface in SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll() as NSArray {
    if let name = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(interface as! SCNetworkInterface),
       let type = SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(interface as! SCNetworkInterface) {
            print("Interface \(name) is of type \(type)")
    }
}
```

can any one help me. I want to use SCNetworkInterface methods in my code. But i found this swift code. I am unable to understand this.especially syntax as!

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the `as!`. It is a **forced cast** from an optional to a specific type. In Objective-C you just have a pointer; type conversions are handled more loosely.

Thus,

```
NSString *name = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(interface);
```

should suffice.

Comment: What could be the interface. when i give en0, it is giving error

Comment: You should take the result of `SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()`, not provide your own. You can examine the result of that call to find out what the interface you need should be.

Comment: I am  new to SCNetworkinterface class , and spending more than a week on this, could you please help me to get over this. I too will learn with you. Could you please translate my snippet to objective -c

Comment: @syammala Do you know any Objective C?

Comment: @AMomchilov Yes i do

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708797/1623781) SO post. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846131/1623781) SO post answers your question.