# Convert Network Interface Name

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to get a list of active network interfaces with end user understandable names. Like the names listed in System Preferences instead of `en0` `en5`.

I have the raw interfaces using `getifaddrs` but haven't been able to find how to take those and get the system names of `Ethernet` or `Wifi`.

Anyone know how to do this? This would be for macOS.

What I have now:

```
    struct ifaddrs *ifap;
    if( getifaddrs(&ifap) == 0 ){
        struct ifaddrs *interface;

        for (interface = ifap; interface != NULL; interface = interface->ifa_next) {
            unsigned int flags = interface->ifa_flags;
            struct sockaddr *addr = interface->ifa_addr;

            // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
            if ((flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING)) {
                if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET || addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {

                    // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
                    getnameinfo(addr, addr->sa_len, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

                    printf("interface:%s, address:%s\n", interface->ifa_name, host);
                    // MAGIC HERE TO CONVERT ifa_name to "Ethernet" or something
                }

            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with System Configuration on macOS. In Objective-C like so:

```
    CFArrayRef ref = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();
    NSArray* networkInterfaces = (__bridge NSArray *)(ref);
    for(int i = 0; i < networkInterfaces.count; i += 1) {
        SCNetworkInterfaceRef interface = (__bridge SCNetworkInterfaceRef)(networkInterfaces[i]);

        CFStringRef displayName = SCNetworkInterfaceGetLocalizedDisplayName(interface);
        CFStringRef bsdName = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(interface);
        NSLog(@"Name:%@  \ninterface: %@\nbsd:%@",displayName, SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(interface), bsdName);

    }
```

The localized display name will be something like `Display Ethernet` or `WiFi` and the BSD name will be something like `en5` which will allow matching to the above code.

This approach doesn't work on iOS, but there aren't really any other configurations on iOS anyway.