# Get description of network adapter using Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, networking

I am using the "getifaddrs" function to receive a list of all network adapters on my MacBook.
I get a list of adapters named "en0", "en1", "utun0" and so on.

Is there a way to get a "human readable" string for these adapters? Like "WiFi 1" for en0?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727807/convert-network-interface-name. That is Objective-C, but it should be  easy to translate it to Swift.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!